# Flex-box justify-content not working whilst align-items does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm trying to move around text with `justify-content` with **flex box** and whilst `align-items` works to move the content vertically, `justify-content` doesn't work to move the content horizontally.

I know I can use `text-align`, however I don't like how it moves all the text to the far right including the sub-title text, which I want to start at the same place as the title does - I believe this would be what `justify-content` would do.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/yYxmLP

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-slider" class="carousel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item item1 active">
            <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="details flex-row">
              <div class="fix-flex">
                <h2>I'm a header title</h2>
                <p class="sub-title">
                  I'm a little sub-title
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item item2">
            <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-8.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="details flex-row">
              <div class="fix-flex">
                <h2>I'm a header title</h2>
                <p class="sub-title">
                  I'm a little sub-title
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {

  position: relative;

  .details {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;

    h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

  }

  &.item2 {

    .details {
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: flex-start;      
    }

  }

}

.fix-flex {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

There is more CSS related to the code, but it's related to `bootstrap`.

Comment: Could you clarify in what way this isn't right? It looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: As for `justify-content` aligning items to start at the same spot...no, that's not really the case. An image of what this is supposed to look like would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean? Currently it's aligned in the center because of `text-align: center;` - though you'll find if you play around with the `justify-content` value it doesn't move.

Comment: That's what I'm saying...I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm wondering why `justify-content` isn't working to move the text around. Simple as that.

Comment: Where is it supposed to move it? Remember you're not moving the text, you're moving the elements,,,that may not be the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why you need `text-align: center` to actually center the text :) It's supposed to move it to the correct position, whether that be start, center or right.

Comment: I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The **elements** are centered (but 100% wide). I don't know what you mean by "correct" position. Perhaps making a less complex demo might be better,

Comment: Ahh.... I see what you are saying. I see why it is not working now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @paulie_D's comments I realised it had to do with the `fix-flex` class which had a style of `width: 100%;` set and was wrapped around the content I was trying to justify and hence it really couldn't move it.

This was also pointed out by Adrian Eufracio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573767/472501); however removing the div altogether would cause the issue I was trying to prevent; so I had to leave the div in the code but just remove the `width: 100%;` from the styles and I can now justify the content and the text doesn't wrap.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/jbeOrP

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-slider" class="carousel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item item1 active">
            <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="details flex-row">
              <div class="fix-flex">
                <h2>I'm a header title</h2>
                <p class="sub-title">
                  I'm a little sub-title
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item item2">
            <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-8.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="details flex-row">
              <div class="fix-flex">
                <h2>I'm a header title</h2>
                <p class="sub-title">
                  I'm a little sub-title
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {

  position: relative;

  .details {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;

    h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

  }

  &.item2 {

    .details {
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: flex-start;      
    }

  }

}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is due to your fix-flex class. It has a width of 100%. It is being centered with justify-content:center but since the element is the same size of its container it is not visually obvious that it is working. Check out my fork of your codepen.

[Fork of your codepen](http://codepen.io/adrianeufracio/pen/EVdaQM#0)

This should be removed

```
.fix-flex {width:100%;}
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that out after reading @paulie_D's comments. However, removing it didn't work for me, I had to *leave* the div, but remove the `100%`. Removing the div altogether caused the issues why the div was put there in the first place :)